# Creating a toString method that returns an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

I have been recently asked to write a `toString` method that returns a number in an array as follows:

> after every 3 digits from the right-hand side of the number it should
>   add a comma , but if the digits of the number were 3 or less it
>   doesn't add a comma.

But I've encountered a problem: The method always returns the value `0,`. How can I adjust the code to return the correct format?

```
public class BigNum {

    int[] num;
    final int MAX_DIGITS = 50;


    public BigNum() {
        this.num = new int[MAX_DIGITS];
        this.num[0] = 0;
        for(int i=1 ; i<this.num.length ; i++) 
            this.num[i] = -1;
    }

    public BigNum(long n) {

        int number = (int)n;
        this.num = new int[MAX_DIGITS];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.num.length; i++) {
            num[i] = number % 10;
            number /= 10; 
        }
    }

    public String toString(){

    String toReturn = "";
        this.num = new int[MAX_DIGITS];

        for(int i=0 ; i<this.num.length ; i++)
            if(this.num.length>=1 && this.num.length<=3)
                toReturn = num[i] + "";

        for(int j=0 ; j<this.num.length ; j+=3)
            toReturn = num[j] + "," ;


        return toReturn;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "toString method that returns an array" since `toString` in your code doesn't return an array.

Comment: the method should return a string that prints the number that appears in the array as I said above. Sorry about my poor language.

Comment: remove this line `this.num = new int[MAX_DIGITS];`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: where is your main function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below piece of code. Remember to copy the BigNum constructor. There are a following changes made to following code:

1. Creating the instance array length equal to number of digits in the input and not equal to MAX_DIGITS.
2. Changed the toString method.

   ```
   public BigNum(long n) {

   int number = (int)n;
   int[] tempNum = new int[MAX_DIGITS];

   int counter=0;
   while(number>0) {
       tempNum[counter] = number % 10;
       number /= 10; 
       counter++;
   }
   this.num = Arrays.copyOfRange(tempNum, 0, counter);

   }

   public String toString(){
   String toReturn = "";
   if(this.num.length>=1 && this.num.length<=3) {
       for(int i=this.num.length-1 ; i>=0 ; i--) {
           toReturn += num[i];
       }
   }else {
       int commaPos = this.num.length%3==0?3:this.num.length%3;
       int counter=0;
       while(counter<this.num.length) {
           if(counter==commaPos) {
               toReturn+=",";
               commaPos+=3;
           }
           toReturn+=num[this.num.length-1-counter]
           counter++;
       }
   }
   return toReturn;
   }
   ```

I tested the above using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigNum bn = new BigNum(1234567);        
    System.out.println(bn);
}
```

**Output**: 1,234,567

Comment: The number should be of the type array

Comment: I didn't get your point.Are you referring to input `new BigNum(1234567)`? I haven't changed the type of the `num`. It' s still int array. That;s why I am able to do `this.num.length`

Comment: No , sorry I meant this int number = (int)n;  I'm asked to make it of type array at the start

Comment: Actually I have taken this line of code from the question posted above. Could you edit the question so that it becomes more clear?

Comment: The Constructor is not clear for me (on the question, not your answer ;) ).

Comment: toReturn += num[i] + ""; I don't understand things like this !? Why append nothing => + "" ?

Comment: @Shim-Sao It's not required in this case as `toReturn ` is initialized with "". But if we have something like `int i=5;` and we do `String s = i;` then compiler won't allow that as you can't conver `int` to `String`. But if we do `String s == i+"";` compiler will allow that. But as I mentioned earlier it was not required in this case. Also edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for explanation :)

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you :)

Comment: @YasmeenDeis mark the answer as expected if it helped you.